# UIPanGestureRecognizer Swift Capture relative translation

Tags: swift

I need to capture relative translation, I m only dealing with the x-direction

let us say I m swiping in one direction right to left (ex: -13.XXXX to -68.XXXX), then without lifting my finger I swipe left to right (ex: -68.XXXX to +30.XXXX)
How do I capture that is the particular point translation changed
I m trying to use velocity which ended up being 0 in the beginning and when the direction changed.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. When the velocity is 0 save the translation. Then the relative translation will be the translation less the saved translation. The only gotcha here is: does the velocity always go to zero in a direction change? Probably not.

Comment: This is not entirely clear. Are you trying to detect when the direction changed? Just keep the previous velocity and see if the sign of the current velocity is different. By the way, when you change direction, I would not assume that you’ll see the event with a x-velocity of zero. As you switch from swiping left to swiping right, you might just see velocity go from a negative number to a positive number, but without ever seeing precisely a velocity of zero. And even if you did see a velocity of zero, you have no assurances that you actually changed direction vs just pausing.

Comment: @SteveO'Connor yes, it does. velocity goes to zero when changing the direction when the user changes direction slowly

Comment: @Rob thanks Rob, changed direction vs just pausing I haven't considered this scenario, ur right. I think rather than depending on velocity, I should just depend on translation and implement Steve solution or I need to check the velocity sign, make use of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’d suggest calculating direction from the velocity:

```
enum Direction {
    case left
    case right
}

extension Direction {
    static func direction(from velocity: CGFloat) -> Direction? {
        if velocity < 0 {
            return .left
        } else if velocity > 0 {
            return .right
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Then, keep track of the previous direction and detect changes in direction:

```
var previousDirection: Direction?

@objc func handlePan(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let velocity = gesture.velocity(in: gesture.view).x

    guard let direction = Direction.direction(from: velocity) else { return }

    if direction != previousDirection {
        if previousDirection == nil {
            print("starting", direction)
        } else {
            print("changing direction to", direction)
        }

        previousDirection = direction
    }
}
```

Note, you cannot rely on tests for zero velocity, as often when you go from panning left to panning right (or vice versa), it may go from one direction to another, without ever encountering a velocity of precisely zero. You might occasionally, but not as a general rule.